# Does Stone gaunlet and Aquila work on followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does Stone gaunlet and Aquila work on followers?

I plan to use all skills access on the follower, now I need to make sure my follower are tough enough.

Diablo 3 patch 2.7.1

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page on followers](https://maxroll.gg/resources/follower-mechanics):

No, the Secondary effects of the **Stone Gauntlets** (Getting hit increases your armor by 50%, but reduces your movement speed by 15% and attack speed by 20%. This effect stacks up to 5 times.) and **Aquila Cuirass** (While above 94% primary resource, all damage taken is reduced by 50%. [90 - 95]%) do not work. Additional items with set bonuses, movement speed bonuses, and resource bonuses do not apply to Followers. This is likely because followers don't have resource pools, and have a fixed movement speed.